# What does a "3/4 circle with a plus inside it" icon on the notification mean?

Tags: notification-icons, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

After I recently updated my phone about a day ago, this strange sign that looks like a 3/4 circle with a plus inside it showed up on the top left that I have never seen before.

[image]

Does anyone know what it means? Or how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 16):

If this is the icon you are looking for then it's the Data Saver icon in Mobile /Network Data option:

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 8):

Status bar icon is to show that `Data Saver` is ON. Data Saver controls data usage of device .

To turnoff Data saver, go to Settings-> Data usage -> Data Saver and turnoff. There you can see an option named `unrestricted data access`, which you can set application that can use data, even if data saver is ON (Eg. Google Play Services ).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found out. It's the "reached the data cap limit" icon. Note that it's not found anywhere.

The icon is visible here, near "Data usage". The same icon will appear in the top notification bar:

[image: screenshots]
<sup>Screenshots (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: This now sounds like an icon from your service - which is? Please, how did you find this out, if it is "not found anywhere?".

Comment: @wbogacz AOSP, no doubt.

Answer (score 1):

- Go to "CONNECTIONS" >> DATA USAGE >> DATA SAVER >> turn OFF!

The icon disappears

[image: a] [image: b]

Comment: That's a great explanation of how to turn off Data Saver on **your** phone, but you don't say what phone that is, and it doesn't appear to be what the OP is using. Also, the question is about what the icon means, and has already been answered. It's most helpful if you can focus on questions that don't already have a good answer.