# What is this icon that showed up on my android?

Tags: notification-icons

Any one has any idea what this notification icon means?
[image: strange icon]

Thanks

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/169883/3-4-circle-with-plus-in-it/170034#170034

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like the Data Saver Icon, a feature used to reduce your mobile data usage. Note that this is not set by your network provider but by the user (although there may be a default). Go into settings to check!