# What is this ICON -circle with a plus sign in the middle?

Tags: notification-icons

This icon showed up a few days ago, but I have no clue what it is. I have done a Google image search and can't find it.

This is on my Samsung S7 in the notification bar.  [image]

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/169883/3-4-circle-with-plus-in-it/170034#170034

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! For your next issue, may I recommend you our site search? I've just used your description terms, and see what they brought up: [circle with a plus](/search?q=circle+with+a+plus) :)

Answer (score 1):

Data Saver is On.

You can toggle it off via Settings - Connections - Data Usage - Data Saver